# Split AC Unit won't turn on after an explosion sound

Tags: electrical, hvac, air-conditioning

I have a Split AC Unit and it had been working fine for a while, but one day I turned on the switch for my AC and I heard a loud explosion sound emanate from the indoor unit. After that, I couldn't turn on my AC anymore. It doesn't respond to the remote and the manual override buttons on the AC itself don't work either. In fact, it doesn't even make a beep when I turn the switch on anymore.

I did a bit of googling and some sources claim that the explosion sound plus the fact that it won't turn on might indicate a blown fuse. I decided to open up the unit to see If I could replace the fuse but from what I can see, there is no fuse and all the capacitors look fine. I'm not particularly good at electronics so maybe I'm missing something but here are some pictures:

[image: PCB of indoor unit]

[image: PCB of indoor unit]

Any ideas what might be causing it to fail? Also, are those wires supposed to be hanging out? They were like that when I opened it.

## EDIT: More info

Here is a picture of the wires connecting to the indoor unit.
[image: wires connecting to ac]

Here is a picture of the switch used to turn the AC on. Breaker isn't tripped.
[image: switch with light on]

Here is a picture of the PCB schematic that was on the shroud of the indoor unit. Though I think this is just a generic schematic and not exactly the one used by the AC.
[image: schematic]

Comment: Welcome to the site! A few follow-up questions: How is this unit connected to power — is there an outlet it plugs into? If so, is it a standard outlet for other things like a lamp where you could plug something else in to confirm there is still electricity reaching that outlet? Have you checked the electrical panel to see if any breakers are tripped (i.e. in their middle position)? Pictues of the wire going into the wall and any plug and the electrical panel could be helpful to the community in figuring out the answer.

Comment: @statueuphemism Hey, thanks for the help! The AC is powered by a switch that is used by the AC only. Here is an image: https://i.imgur.com/MAkUxe5.jpeg. I can confirm that the breaker isn't tripped because I checked the hanging wires in the AC using a multimeter. I will update the question with more info.

Comment: An explosion does not sound like a fuse. Burst pipe maybe?

Comment: Are there proper connectors inside the splice or is it just tape?  Why not replace the cord by directly connecting the supply lines rather than splicing them this way inside the unit?  Have you taken any simple measurements, like, is there power at the main power terminals?       Can you look carefully for signs of either an electrical arc (look for soot) or an actual explosion (look for fragments of metal, plastic, etc.)

Comment: In your first picture, your coils look to be severely caked and covered in dust/dirt.  Dirty coils will make the AC work much harder to cool, as it reduces airflow through the fins and severely reduces the cooling capacity, and likely will cause icing on some of the coils.    This wouldn't be the direct cause of your non-functioning unit, but could be a contributor to it wearing out or failing in some manner in the future.

Comment: Loud bangs can be burst capacitors. Examine board for caps that have exploded(obvious). Replace if found.

Comment: @bsd From what I can see, there doesn't seem to be any burst capacitors but I feel like I'm missing something here. Every indoor unit should have a fuse, right? The schematic says as much but the PCB that's in my unit seems to be completely different than the schematic. Maybe it's obvious that there is a second board or something and I just can't see it, if so I would love to know how to reach it!

Answer (score 0):

Those funny hanging wires are splices.  They connect the electrical supply to the mini-split heat pump.  One of the splices has failed due to arcing, because the connection was poorly made.

It's also possible that the insulation wrap was done poorly, and the wires shorted either to each other, or to parts of the unit inside.

Comment: Thank you for answering but correct me if I'm wrong: as I understand it, when you refer to heat pump you mean that the AC can heat as well as cool, right? If so, then you should know that this model doesn't have heating, only cooling. Also, it might be different where you live but in my country, it's standard practice for air conditioners to have a switch to turn them on or off, especially split ACs. You literally can't find a house that doesn't have switch for its air conditioner.

Comment: @Harris interesting.  Surprising they nerf what is plainly a mini-split heat pump.     Regarding a switch to cut power, that may be a mandatory disconnect switch (we have those too)... but for daily turn on/off I would advise following the unit's instructions.